# Routing not correct in MERN, following a YouTube Video and downloaded the source code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, vite

First question from myself in stackoverflow.

tldr:Watched followed a YouTube video and downloaded from his github link for the course code but I seem to be having problems in the routing from all the other questions I have read on stackoverflow.

I have been following this YouTube Video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpQbwtSiZ7E. I downloaded the source code from his link https://github.com/dejwid/airbnb-clone . From all the questions that I have been reading from this seems to be a routing problem. I do not know if it was during the cloning or following his video but the network section from the browser inspect has been showing 404 for UserContext.js(googlechrome) RegisterPage.jsx(googlechrome) axios.jsx(in firefox) and 204 OPTIONS preflight. Most of it very similar to his actual github code other than the .env file and app.listen(); in the index.js at the end.
images of some errors.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U873p.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyiI5.png)

api/.env

```
API_PORT = 5173
MONGO_URL = "mongodb+srv://admin:admin@cluster0.c98j5op.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&appName=Cluster0"
```

client/.env

```
VITE_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:4000/
```

RegisterPage.jsx

```
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function RegisterPage() {
  const [name,setName] = useState('');
  const [email,setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password,setPassword] = useState('');
  
  async function registerUser(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    try {
      await axios.post('/register', {
        name,
        email,
        password,
      });
      alert('Registration successful. Now you can log in');
    } catch (e) {
      alert('Registration failed. Please try again later');
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="mt-4 grow flex items-center justify-around">
      <div className="mb-64">
        <h1 className="text-4xl text-center mb-4">Register</h1>
        <form className="max-w-md mx-auto" onSubmit={registerUser}>
          <input type="text"
                 placeholder="John Doe"
                 value={name}
                 onChange={ev => setName(ev.target.value)} />
          <input type="email"
                 placeholder="your@email.com"
                 value={email}
                 onChange={ev => setEmail(ev.target.value)} />
          <input type="password"
                 placeholder="password"
                 value={password}
                 onChange={ev => setPassword(ev.target.value)} />
          <button className="primary">Register</button>
          <div className="text-center py-2 text-gray-500">
            Already a member? <Link className="underline text-black" to={'/login'}>Login</Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const User = require('./models/User.js');
const Place = require('./models/Place.js');
const Booking = require('./models/Booking.js');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const imageDownloader = require('image-downloader');
const {S3Client, PutObjectCommand} = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const mime = require('mime-types');

require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();

const bcryptSalt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
const jwtSecret = 'fasefraw4r5r3wq45wdfgw34twdfg';
const bucket = 'dawid-booking-app';

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use('/uploads', express.static(__dirname+'/uploads'));
app.use(cors({
  credentials: true,
  origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
}));

async function uploadToS3(path, originalFilename, mimetype) {
  const client = new S3Client({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: {
      accessKeyId: process.env.S3_ACCESS_KEY,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.S3_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    },
  });
  const parts = originalFilename.split('.');
  const ext = parts[parts.length - 1];
  const newFilename = Date.now() + '.' + ext;
  await client.send(new PutObjectCommand({
    Bucket: bucket,
    Body: fs.readFileSync(path),
    Key: newFilename,
    ContentType: mimetype,
    ACL: 'public-read',
  }));
  return `https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${newFilename}`;
}

function getUserDataFromReq(req) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    jwt.verify(req.cookies.token, jwtSecret, {}, async (err, userData) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      resolve(userData);
    });
  });
}

app.get('/api/test', (req,res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  res.json('test ok');
});
console.log(process.env.MONGO_URL);
app.post('/api/register', async (req,res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  const {name,email,password} = req.body;

  try {
    const userDoc = await User.create({
      name,
      email,
      password:bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcryptSalt),
    });
    res.json(userDoc);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(422).json(e);
  }

});

app.post('/api/login', async (req,res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  const {email,password} = req.body;
  const userDoc = await User.findOne({email});
  if (userDoc) {
    const passOk = bcrypt.compareSync(password, userDoc.password);
    if (passOk) {
      jwt.sign({
        email:userDoc.email,
        id:userDoc._id
      }, jwtSecret, {}, (err,token) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.cookie('token', token).json(userDoc);
      });
    } else {
      res.status(422).json('pass not ok');
    }
  } else {
    res.json('not found');
  }
});

app.get('/api/profile', (req,res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  const {token} = req.cookies;
  if (token) {
    jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, {}, async (err, userData) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      const {name,email,_id} = await User.findById(userData.id);
      res.json({name,email,_id});
    });
  } else {
    res.json(null);
  }
});

app.post('/api/logout', (req,res) => {
  res.cookie('token', '').json(true);
});


app.post('/api/upload-by-link', async (req,res) => {
  const {link} = req.body;
  const newName = 'photo' + Date.now() + '.jpg';
  await imageDownloader.image({
    url: link,
    dest: '/tmp/' +newName,
  });
  const url = await uploadToS3('/tmp/' +newName, newName, mime.lookup('/tmp/' +newName));
  res.json(url);
});

const photosMiddleware = multer({dest:'/tmp'});
app.post('/api/upload', photosMiddleware.array('photos', 100), async (req,res) => {
  const uploadedFiles = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
    const {path,originalname,mimetype} = req.files[i];
    const url = await uploadToS3(path, originalname, mimetype);
    uploadedFiles.push(url);
  }
  res.json(uploadedFiles);
});

app.post('/api/places', (req,res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  const {token} = req.cookies;
  const {
    title,address,addedPhotos,description,price,
    perks,extraInfo,checkIn,checkOut,maxGuests,
  } = req.body;
  jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, {}, async (err, userData) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const placeDoc = await Place.create({
      owner:userData.id,price,
      title,address,photos:addedPhotos,description,
      perks,extraInfo,checkIn,checkOut,maxGuests,
    });
    res.json(placeDoc);
  });
});

app.get('/api/user-places', (req,res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  const {token} = req.cookies;
  jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, {}, async (err, userData) => {
    const {id} = userData;
    res.json( await Place.find({owner:id}) );
  });
});

app.get('/api/places/:id', async (req,res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  const {id} = req.params;
  res.json(await Place.findById(id));
});

app.put('/api/places', async (req,res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  const {token} = req.cookies;
  const {
    id, title,address,addedPhotos,description,
    perks,extraInfo,checkIn,checkOut,maxGuests,price,
  } = req.body;
  jwt.verify(token, jwtSecret, {}, async (err, userData) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    const placeDoc = await Place.findById(id);
    if (userData.id === placeDoc.owner.toString()) {
      placeDoc.set({
        title,address,photos:addedPhotos,description,
        perks,extraInfo,checkIn,checkOut,maxGuests,price,
      });
      await placeDoc.save();
      res.json('ok');
    }
  });
});

app.get('/api/places', async (req,res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  res.json( await Place.find() );
});

app.post('/api/bookings', async (req, res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  const userData = await getUserDataFromReq(req);
  const {
    place,checkIn,checkOut,numberOfGuests,name,phone,price,
  } = req.body;
  Booking.create({
    place,checkIn,checkOut,numberOfGuests,name,phone,price,
    user:userData.id,
  }).then((doc) => {
    res.json(doc);
  }).catch((err) => {
    throw err;
  });
});



app.get('/api/bookings', async (req,res) => {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);
  const userData = await getUserDataFromReq(req);
  res.json( await Booking.find({user:userData.id}).populate('place') );
});

app.listen(4000);
```

UserContext.jsx

```
import {createContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import {data} from "autoprefixer";

export const UserContext = createContext({});

export function UserContextProvider({children}) {
  const [user,setUser] = useState(null);
  const [ready,setReady] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      axios.get('/profile').then(({data}) => {
        setUser(data);
        setReady(true);
      });
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={{user,setUser,ready}}>
      {children}
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

I have tried to add /api on the path of the base URL but it shows just a blank page. I have tried to change app.listen(); in index.js (at the end) to 4000 3000 5000 5173. I have tried to change the API_PORT = 5173 in .env to 4000 5173 5000. I have asked Perplexity ai and chatgpt 3.5 but they only give generic answers taht have not worked. I do not know what else to do. This deeply shows my lack of knowledge but I would also like to see someone get answer because almost all the answers on the other questions or forums have not worked for me.

Edit: I have added a .env with VITE_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:4000/ in it. After a great advice from @Phil. Changed the api.listen(5173); to api.listen(4000).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a quick look in the source repo, it looks like it attempts to [set the Axios `baseURL`](https://github.com/dejwid/airbnb-clone/blob/master/client/src/App.jsx#L16) using

```js
axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL;
```

but there's no such value in the [`.env` file](https://github.com/dejwid/airbnb-clone/blob/master/client/.env).

You'll also need to use different ports for the client and server. Vite by default uses `5173` so use something like this in `api/index.js`

```js
app.listen(4000);
```

and in the `client/.env` file...

```properties
VITE_API_BASE_URL=http://localhost:4000/api/
```

Note that I've included the `/api` base path in the base URL since all your routes seem to include it and your client-side code doesn't.

Comment: There is finally a small change in the output. Although it's still unresponsive. The error has changed. Before it was just 404 but now there is also a 204 pre flight error.

Comment: That doesn't give me much to go on. What URL are you opening in your browser? For the CORS config to work, it should be `http://localhost:5173`

Comment: yes an origin for the cors has been given has 'http://localhost:5173' in the index.js. And the URL that I'm currently on is 'http://localhost:5173/register' .

Comment: @PhurbuTsering have you restarted the Vite dev server since adding to the `client/.env` file. You need to manually stop it (`Ctrl+C`) and start it again (`yarn dev`)

Comment: Hello @Phil yes I did as you instructed and there has been no changes.

Comment: @PhurbuTsering well, your route is registered under `/api/register` but you're only making a request to `/register`. Perhaps you should include the `/api` path in the base URL

Comment: when I try to run **nodemon index.js** on the api terminal it gives a Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::4000 and app crashes.

Comment: as instructed I have tried adding a /api on the url but it just shows a blank white page.

Comment: I have edited and added an image of the photos of the list of errors it shows. I will try to find answers from my side too.

Comment: You're not meant to open `http://localhost:5173/api/register` in your browser